# My device language is in ltr change, i want to change my app's language into rtl for Arabic language in android

Tags: android, localization, right-to-left

My device language is in ltr change, i want to change my app's language into rtl for Arabic language in android.
             After changing app language into Arabic app's layout not changing into rtl they are remain showing into ltr. I also  **android:supportsRtl="true"** in manifest file but nothing change.

Comment: If you're changing the app's language in app-  that won't work.  Use the actual phone locale.  Everything is set up to work that way.  Trying to make end runs around it only end in problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all, i solve my problem by doing Configuration conf = new Configuration(); while setting locale.